# Find next highest unique number from the given digits

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Given a set of n symbols, a size k, and a combination of length k of non-repeating characters from the symbol set, write only an ITERATIVE algorithm to print the next highest unique number that can be made.

Ex:

```
Symbols =[1,2,3,4,5]
size = 3;
given combination = 123, result = 124
given combination = 254, result = 312
```

Comment: Good interviewers can tell if you have a canned response to these things. They like it better if you have to work it out, because they can see your problem-solving process, which is more important than just knowing the solution.

Comment: I gave a solution like so , 
Take a sorted double ended queue of available numbers , initialise with available numbers,
1. start with units digit , check if higher number available, if so replace else, put this number in available list and check tens digit
2. In case you find a number greater than the current digit replace it, and start inserting smaller numbers from the queue.
Can this be made more efficient and are there any flaws?

Comment: example.. {{{
123  available : 45
check 3 .. replace with 4

for 254 available:13
check 4 .. 1,3<4 put 4 in available
check 5 .. not available
check 2 .. available : 1345
insert 2 in available,, replace with 3, follow by 1 and 2

}}}

Comment: I would probably use a TreeSet instead of the queue since you always iterate from the beginning anyway. Otherwise thats the solution i would have proposed.

Comment: I would encode and decode a combination number. (A number for each possible combination) This makes incrementing trivial.

Comment: @Stefan Using a TreeSet wouldn't be more efficient, since looking at both ends of the queue would be necessary for optimization.

Comment: I've never been good with on-the-spot answers to arbitrarily weird things like this. I'd probably write a shell script and do something rude with `sort -n`. :-/

Comment: I'm not clear on the iterative algorithm bit. Can you please elaborate ?Also for 254, shouldn't the next highest unique number be: 354 ?

Comment: @Gordon. Actually he's right! .. I dont need to look from both ends. I want the "next bigger number" not the highest of the available numbers. so even a single ended queue/treeset would be alright.

Comment: @BrainyDexter Iterative -- basically nething that does not use recursion--. So a recursive algorithm is prohibited. and well. using the set 12345 you can make 312 right ? and 312<354 so its 312.. I hope this clarifies

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee: Ok. For `next highest unique number`: 254 would be change 2 to 3 = 354, and 354 > 312, so it should be 354 ?

Comment: .. if i ask you wats the next bigger number than 254 that you can make from the digits 12345 wouldnt it be 312.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pseudocode algorithm to do this:

```
int n = length(Symbols);
int k = length(A);
// TRACK WHICH LETTERS ARE STILL AVAILABLE
available = sort(Symbols minus A);
// SEARCH BACKWARDS FOR AN ENTRY THAT CAN BE INCREASED
for (int i=k-1; i>=0; --i) {
    // LOOK FOR NEXT SMALLEST AVAILABLE LETTER
    for (int j=0; j<n-k; ++j) {
        if (A[i] < available[j]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j < n-k) {
        // CHANGE A[i] TO THAT, REMOVE IT FROM AVAILABLE
        int tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = available[j];
        available[j] = tmp;
        // RESET SUBSEQUENT ENTRIES TO SMALLEST AVAILABLE
        for (j=i+1; i<k; ++j) {
            A[j] = available[i+1-j];
        }
        return A;
     } else {
         // A[i] MUST BE LARGER THAN AVAILABLE, SO APPEND TO END
         available = append(available,A[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: I gave the same answer! .. the interviewer said i could optimise it more!!! see comment on my post.!

Answer (score 2):

```
public class IncrementSybmols {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        List<Integer> syms = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);

        test(syms, 3, Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(1,2,4));
        test(syms, 3, Arrays.asList(2,5,4), Arrays.asList(3,1,2));

        test(syms, 3, Arrays.asList(4,3,5), Arrays.asList(4,5,1));
        test(syms, 3, Arrays.asList(5,4,2), Arrays.asList(5,4,3));
        test(syms, 3, Arrays.asList(5,4,3), null);
    }

    private static void test(List<Integer> syms, int n, List<Integer> in, List<Integer> exp) {
        List<Integer> out = increment(syms, n, in);
        System.out.println(in+" -> "+out+": "+( exp==out || exp.equals(out)?"OK":"FAIL"));
    }

    private static List<Integer> increment(List<Integer> allSyms, int n, List<Integer> in){
        TreeSet<Integer> availableSym = new TreeSet<Integer>(allSyms);
        availableSym.removeAll(in);

        LinkedList<Integer> current = new LinkedList<Integer>(in);

        // Remove symbols beginning from the tail until a better/greater symbols is available.
        while(!current.isEmpty()){
            Integer last = current.removeLast();
            availableSym.add(last);

            // look for greater symbols
            Integer next = availableSym.higher(last);
            if( next != null ){
                // if there is a greater symbols, append it
                current.add(next);
                availableSym.remove(next);
                break;
            }
        }

        // if there no greater symbol, then *shrug* there is no greater number
        if( current.isEmpty() )
            return null;

        // fill up with smallest symbols again
        while(current.size() < n){
            Integer next = availableSym.first();
            availableSym.remove(next);
            current.add(next);
        }

        return current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are iterating (backwards) across the digits you do not have to check the lowest available every time, instead you can check the last checked digit versus the current, if it is less, skip to the next digit while adding the current to available, if it is more then check the available to find the lowest(higher than current) possible and fill in the rest with lowest from queue.

```
i.e. 254

current = 4      // 4 < 1,3  so no higher available
last_checked = 4 // available = {1, 3, 4}
current = 5      // 4 < 5 so no higher available
last_checked = 5 // available = {1, 3, 4, 5}
current = 2      // 5 > 2 so search available for lowest possible(higher than 2) = 3
set 3,_,_        // Then just add lowest elements until full: 3,1,2 = 312
```

This way you only have to look at the available symbols once, and you are only comparing at most k times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method out:

```
public int nextCombo(int[] symbols, int combo, int size) {
    String nc = "";
    symbols = java.util.Arrays.sort(symbols);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) nc += Integer.toString(symbols[symbols.length - 1]);
    if (Integer.parseInt(nc) == combo) return combo; //provided combo is the largest possible so end the method
    nc = "";
    int newCombo = 0;
    while (newCombo < combo) { //repeat this process until the new combination is greater than the provided one
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //keep appending numbers from the symbol array onto the new combo until the size limit is reached
            nc += Integer.toString(symbols[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * size)]);
        }
        newCombo = Integer.parseInt(nc);
    }
    return newCombo;
}
```